# Why does Stack Exchange still not support browser notifications?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, notifications

I have been wondering why Stack Exchange, especially Stack Overflow does not show browser notification.

Let me explain my situation. Suppose I have asked an question on Stack Overflow, and I am expecting some feedback and answers on same. But then I get caught up in my work, so I closed the tab or forgot about the question, or I have just simply closed my browser. But meanwhile somebody added a comment or an answer on my question, so naturally I will miss that and won't know about it until I reopen the website.

Now considering the situation about which is most common for most of the developers out there, how cool would it be that they get notified instantly whenever some changes happens in their thread?

And remember we can always control our notification settings via the browser. For the folks who says it's annoying when they are expecting too much response.

I have already tried visiting similar threads and found a Chrome extension for the same. But it doesn't works for me. It gets stuck while granting permissions. A link to the extension [is here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/desktop-notifications-for/ijglncoabcgieiokjmgdogpefdblmnle?hl=en).

Comment: I have already visited thread above and found a chrome extension for same. But it doesn't  works for me. It gets stuck while granting permissions.

Comment: @GeekWithGlasses: If you have "closed my browser", wouldn't that mean you wouldn't get notifications?

Comment: @NicolBolas Chrome, as an example, runs in the background all the time, even with all browser windows closed.

Comment: @TheWanderer: I guess that's reasons 2,103 not to use Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate this doesn't answer your question (that's one for the developers) there is a built in workaround. When you ask a question there's a check box you can tick:

[image]

It might not be as realtime as desktop notifications but it will happen whether or not you have the browser tab open.

Comment: There are indeed many workarounds/plugins/etc., but nothing is quite as good as true web notification support (works on mobile/no stored clutter on device or mailbox/natively works in browser without plugins)

Comment: Yeah native support would be the best, But workaround can be made as suggested above via emails.